# Kerberos with LDAP Installation

Tags: ldap, kerberos, openldap

i wanted to install openldap with kerberos
when i try this command :  "/etc/init.d/krb5-kdc start"
i got error : 
krb5kdc: cannot initialize realm EXAMPLE.COM - see log file for details
log file : krb5kdc: Can not fetch master key (error: No such file or directory). - while fetching master key K/M for realm EXAMPLE.COM
whats wrong?
How can i fix the problem

my krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
[realms]
    EXAMPLE.COM = {
            #default_domain = example.com
            #admin_server = kdc01.example.com
            #kdc = kdc01.example.com
            database_module = openldap_ldapconf
    }
[domain_realm]
    .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
    example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
[dbdefaults]
    ldap_kerberos_container_dn = dc=example,dc=com
[dbmodules]
    openldap_ldapconf = {
            db_library = kldap
            ldap_kdc_dn = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
            ldap_kadmind_dn = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
            ldap_service_password_file = /etc/krb5kdc/service.keyfile
            ldap_servers = ldapi:///
            ldap_conns_per_server = 5
    }

[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/krb5/kdc.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/krb5/kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
[kdc]
    profile = /etc/krb5kdc/kdc.conf
```

Comment: This is for serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For kerberos with ldap backend you can init the Kerberos realm with:

```
 kdb5_ldap_util -D cn=admin,o=org -H ldaps://ldap-server1.mit.edu create -subtrees o=org -sscope SUB -r ATHENA.MIT.EDU
```

More info http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/admin_commands/kdb5_ldap_util.html

Comment: So please, mark my answer as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to init your realm as a first step, if you use the heimdal server it's done like this:

```
 # kadmin -l 
kadmin> init EXAMPLE.ORG
```

If kadmin -l doesn't work, then you don't run heimdal (mit is my second guess) and can try to replace that with kadmin.local

Comment: http://pastie.org/8036075